# Are goals the only way to track conversion rate of non-landing pages, in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

It seems easy to look at conversion rates of landing pages in google analytics via:

behaviour > site content > landing pages

(there's an 'ecommerce conversion rate' column displaying conversion rate for each landing page).

However, if I want to look at the conversion rate for a page that a user wouldn't "land" on / enter the site on, such as a search results page, i can't work out how to do this.

Other than setting up goals. I wondered if there was an easier way?

Ideally - when i go to:

site content > all pages

If it had the ecommerce column, that would be ideal. But doesn't seem possible.